# Reading multiple large csv files of size 10GB plus parallel in python

Tags: python, csv, python-multiprocessing

I have a client shared feed of 100 GB in 10 CSV files each having 10GB.

when we want to parse all files to create one final feed file, it will take more than one day to complete.

So I have done parsing multiple CSV files parallelly using python multiprocessing pool.

I have done testing for three files of size 30 GB using below code and is taking around 10 mins to complete.

Can somebody look into my code and help me to improve the below code to parse faster or suggest me any better way to parse files.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import csv
import codecs

def unicode_csv_reader(csvfile,dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        for row in csv.reader(codecs.iterencode(codecs.iterdecode(f,"utf-8"), "utf-8"),quotechar='"',delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True,dialect=dialect, **kwargs):
            yield [e.decode("utf-8") for e in row]


def process_file(name):
    ''' Process one file:'''
    csv_reader=unicode_csv_reader(name)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row is not None and len(row) != 0 and row[1]=="in stock" and row[18]=="Book":
        linePrint=row[0]+"\t"+row[6]+"\t"+row[12]+"\t"+row[4]+"\t"+row[17]+"\t"+row[17]+"\t"+row[10]+"\t"+row[9]+"\t"+"\t"+row[18]+"\t"+row[18]+"\t"+row[8]+"\t"+row[8]+"\t\t"
        print linePrint.encode("utf-8")


def process_files_parallel():
    ''' Process each file in parallel via Poll.map() '''
    pool=Pool(processes=4)
    results=pool.map(process_file, ["t1.csv","t2.csv","t3.csv"])
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start=time.time()
    res=process_files_parallel()
    print res
```

I'm running this file in my ubuntu machine like below

```
python multiprocessfiles.py > finalfeed.csv
```

Sample data from client feed

```
"id", "availability", "condition", "description", "image_link", "link", "title", "brand", "google_product_category", "price", "sale_price", "currency", "android_url", "android_app_name", "android_package", "discount_percentage","discount_value", "category", "super_category"
"5780705772161","in stock","new","(ise) Genetics: Analysis Of Eenes And Genomics","https://rukminim1.client.com/image/600/600/jeiukcw0/book/9/8/2/medicinal-inorganic-chemistry-original-imaf37yeyhyhzwfm.jpeg?q=90","http://www.client.com/ise-genetics-analysis-eenes-genomics/p/itmd32spserbxyhf?pid=5780705772161&marketplace=client&cmpid=content_appretar_BooksMedia_Book","(ise) Genetics: Analysis Of Eenes And Genomics","W. Jones","Books","3375","1893","INR","client://fk.dl/de_wv_CL%7Csem_--_http%3A%2F%2Fwww.client.com%2Fise-genetics-analysis-eenes-genomics%2Fp%2Fitmd32spserbxyhf~q~pid%3D5780705772161%26marketplace%3Dclient_--_cmpid_--_content_appretar_BooksMedia_Book","client","com.client.android","43","1482","BooksMedia","Book"
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the order of the lines from the various files does not matter?

Comment: @illiteratecoder, Yea, for me the order of lines doesn't matter, as I want all the lines shd be in one final feed file, it doesn't matter where the product line. For ex: if line 10 from t1.csv  and line 5 from t2.csv shd be in any line in the final file.

Comment: @Chethu Can you post a short example how your data looks like?

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer Added sample client data

Comment: You may want to upgrade to Python 3 to begin with, to save on that manual UTF-8 roundtripping you're doing with the `csv` module.

Comment: @AKX  Yea, I can upgrade to python3 if you have sample code to achieve the above

Comment: You can use '\t'.join([row[0], ..., row[8]]) to achieve better performance in the linePrint.

Comment: Is this data on a magnetic hard drive? 50MB/sec (30GB / 600 sec) is not bad for reading multiple files at once and writing one all at the same time.

Comment: @Aaron this on ec2 machine

Comment: @Chethu without knowing where the actual speed bottleneck is, all I can suggest then is [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) (in addition to python3 suggestion made earlier). to get started, I would get a live interpreter on your ec2 box and call: `cProfile.run('process_file("t1.csv")')`

Comment: @Aaron oh, I didn't know about that profiling and let me check, see how it will help me. Thanks a lot, Aaron

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly answering your question, this should be doable in [dask](https://dask.org/). It process in parallel by default. Reading multiple files in parallel is as simple as this:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('t*.csv')
```

More details can be found at the provided link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't install module like dask on the production machine. I want to achieve this in pure python way like above

Comment: Got it, but for performance reasons, I would resort to tested tools like bash: `cat t*.csv > ./merged.csv` combines three 10Gb files under 2 min, on cygwin. In native Linux, it would be even faster. That is still around 5 times faster than the code above.

Comment: I cannot merge file like an above-using cat as I need only certain columns from the client feed and I have  to validate all the basic product details shd be present for the PID and need to keep only products where the price is greater than 1000 and if not then exclude that from the final feed.